# Sick LMS Series Sensors

Tags: ros, laser, sicklms, sensor, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All,

I see on the ros.org website that the Sick LMS1xx & LMS2xx sensors are supported in ROS:

1. Does anyone know if the new Sick LMS5xx sensor is supported?
2. Does anyone know of a 360 degree Sick sensor supported in ROS?

Thank you in advance!
Andy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53522/sick-lms-series-sensors/) by [Andrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3812/andrius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We use the [RCPRG package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/LMS1xx) to work with the LMS1xx series sensors via Ethernet. I have played with using it with the LMS5xx, but ran into issues which I think were mainly related to the LMS5xx not being as easy to set up for continuous output as the LMS1xx.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-02-04**:
I just want to notice you, that LMS1xx driver is a bit buggy.

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2013-02-04**:
How so?

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-02-04**:
At least length of  the array for ranges is shorter for higher angular resolution and longer for lower one. You need to swap two lines. And there are probably more bugs - it seems that min and max angles are not set properly etc.

**Comment by [rohan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2278/rohan/) on 2013-02-25**:
Could you please attach the code where the lines needs to be swapped?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-03-21**:
@ZdenekM please file tickets against software you know about bugs in.

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-04-08**:
@rohan: In LMS1xx_node.cpp, find line 55 ("num_values = 541;") and line 59 ("num_values = 1081;"). Swap numeric values.
@tfoote: This code is not released as far as I know. Where and how I can post bug report? I can't find even author's email...

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2013-04-08**:
Now I see it's on github (I thought it's on some svn)... Hm, I will try to fork it and make pull request.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**2.** Since SICK devices are supported in ROS via [sicktoolbox](http://sicktoolbox.sourceforge.net/) the 360deg devices (SICK LD?) should work.

**1.** The LMS511 is not on the list of supported devices in sicktoolbox. However, since LD and some LMS5xx models both has Ethernet intefaces their protocols should be quite similar. We just started to look into this problem and I don't have much information on this right now. We hope to get some results in the next couple of weeks though.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2